# org-mode only highlights some source blocks, not all

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

I write my emacs configuration file in org mode, which works fine, only that org-mode does not highlight some source blocks.

I set `(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)`, but this only seems to take effect for some blocks, while others are not highlighted.

[image]

Anyone has an idea what might cause this?

Comment: What happens if you edit the second block, will that make it highlighted?

Comment: If I edit it with org-edit-special, it gets highlighted

Comment: It is not only that the source block is not natively highlighted also `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC` are not fontified. Maybe that indicates that something near the header `Hydras` breaks font-locking. Search your message buffer for `error`.

Comment: Thank for the hint, the message buffer prints one error:
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 31409) signaled (args-out-of-range #<buffer config.org> 0 2)

Comment: @Florian, and if you edit it in the org file itself, i.e. not using `org-edit-special`.

Comment: @Florian, you could try `font-lock-studio` (available from Melpa), it's a debugger for font-lock keywords. It allows you to single-step the font-lock rules until you find the culprit. Unless the "real" font-lock, this will start the lisp debugger when an error of this kind is found.

Comment: @Lindydancer, if I edit it in the org file itself, nothing changes. Thanks, i will try font-lock-studio.

Comment: @Florian Please write your EDIT as an answer and accept that answer after the grace period.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for comment. I have a similar issue. Also I try it for Emacs 27.0.50 and 26.1 on Windows 10.
Running emacs -Q:[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcqn7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcqn7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Emacs 26.1 fixed the issue.